# Embed VS URLRequest

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

What is better when I am showing images in actionscript 3 . Is it better to use Embed or use urlRequest and show it in loader . I am asking in terms of swf size as well as end user experience .

```
var myImageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var myImageLocation:URLRequest = new URLRequest("images/loading.gif");
myImageLoader.load(myImageLocation);
addChild(myImageLoader)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on the size of what you are trying to load / embed. Embeding makes the filesize of your SWF bigger, what takes longer to load, but once loaded you have all your images.

If you use loader, your SWF is smaller but the user has to wait for the images to load. I think it is better to use the loader and inform the user that you are busy loading images.

Answer (score 1):

Embed is used in such case, the image/swf is used for some default show when the real image/swf hasn't been loaded. For example, in the webgame or socialgame, the role animator sometimes will be big, so before the role animator has been loaded, we'll use a embed swf as the animator, and it will be replaced when the role animator is loaded.

And in this case the  Embed image/swf usually is very simple and the size is small.